# PDF document: How to verify the digital signature using python?

Tags: python, pdf, digital-signature, signature, python-pdfreader

We are doing the RPA project and extract the data PDF to excel using python.
Now we need verify the **digital_signature** in PDF.

Comment: If by `digital_signatures`, you mean "hashes", you can use [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) library.

Comment: I am talking about digital signature which is added by API's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to PDF 1.7 spec a document may contain:

- one or more approval signatures
- at most one certification signature
- at most two usage rights signatures

There are also 2 defined digest computing techniques. So there is no short answer and checking digital signatures might be tricky.

See [PDF 1.7 section 12.8 Digital Signatures](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=466)

As far as I know  there is no ready-to-run python library to check all possible PDF signatures. You may try to use [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/) to browse PDF document structure and to compute and check the signatures. See [few examples](https://pdfreader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/navigate_objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out https://cbrunet.net/python-poppler/usage.html#working-with-documents

which allows to load all PDF metadata as a Python dict.

If you need a dedicated function for signature validation, I think you need to ask specifically for the devs to implement it: https://github.com/cbrunet/python-poppler/issues

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024 there are some initiatives like [endesive](https://pypi.org/project/endesive/).

This library allows you to verify PDF signatures. It uses [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) to read pdf signature fields, [asn1crypto](https://pypi.org/project/asn1crypto/) to parse them and [cryptography](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/) to validate the signatures.